# Add redux middleware to react-admin

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, react-admin

Is there any way to add redux middleware to react-admin?

I've looked at the code and it couldn't find it. The documentation related to middleware I found only has information about being able to add react-admin to an existing app.

Comment: Look here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#custom-sagas

Comment: @MaxAlex thank you for the comment. How do I apply middleware with sagas? I still don't have much experience with sagas.

Comment: Saga appear as separate streams which may be expected different Redux actions, obtain values ​​directly from the store, to process them,
generate new Redux actions. Saga allow you to do very complicated things: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html